# Intuitive way of proving independence between binary variable and random normal variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Given a random normal variable $X\sim N(0,1)$ and a random variable $Z$ with $\mathbb{P}(Z = 1)=\mathbb{P}(Z = -1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and then a third variable $Y = ZX$, I just got done proving that $Y$ also follows a standard normal distribution and that $Y$ and $X$ are dependent, but not correlated, which I believe are standard exercises.

Now, I am being asked if $Y$ and $Z$ are independent and uncorrelated. Intuitively, I would say that when multiplying $Z$ with $X$, since the signs of $X$ are also random, we gain no information about $Y$ from looking at $Z$, which, as far as I understand, would mean that they are independent of each other, and which would result in a very simple line to show that $Cov(Y,Z)=0$. Now I am wondering, is this thought enough to argue my point, or would I need a more sophisticated proof?

Comment: It should be as easily provable. $C(Y,Z) = E(YZ)-E(Y)E(Z) = E(YZ)=E(X)=0.$ (This proves uncorrelatedness.) To prove independence, you use that $X$ and $-X$ are both the same distribution.

Comment: @WillM. Yes, this proof am I am aware of, but my question wasn't about how to prove that $Cov(Y,Z)=0$, but rather about if this intuitive explanation of independence is sufficient in this context.

Comment: It would depend in your instructor. If your instructor were me, I'd say no. If something is "obvious" intuitively, then it should be as easy to provide a one-liner proof. (That is what I tell my students when they provide with "intuition" arguments and give them about half the marks.)

Comment: Thanks for you assessment.

Comment: You could say "intuitively, knowing Z does not provide information on Y since the sign of X is random, and we see that $P(Y \in R \mid Z = 1) = P(X \in R) = P(\mathsf{Norm}(0,1) \in R)$ and similarly $P(Y \in R \mid Z = -1) = P(-X \in R) = P(\mathsf{Norm}(0, 1) \in R)$ does not depend on $Z,$ as expected."